# How to get the time after clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the time between when the user clicks the start button and the stop button. I was able to start and stop the time but I can't get the time. I'm using ajax success function to call `clearInterval` function to stop the time so when I successfully inserted my data. The time will stop and I need to get the time after the stop button is clicked.

I just need to get the variable `cons`. below is my code:

```
$(".start").click(function() {
  var sec = 0;
  var cons = 0;
  siID = setInterval(function() {
    cons = sec++;
    console.log(cons);
  }, 1000);
});

$('.stop').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "Register_c/register_data",
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: {
      registration: {
        TIN: '123'
      }
    },
    success: function(data) {
      window.clearInterval(siID); //stops the counting
      alert(cons); //here i can't get the variable cons
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert('failed');
    }
  });
```

Comment: You need to define `var cons = 0;` outside the `click function` in this case so it's more globally. Else it's only available inside that function

Comment: @Dre As much as I can see you'r tryin to measure time execution of your method?

Comment: You need to change the scope of `cons` so that it's accessible to both functions. You also need to remove `async: false` as it's terrible practice. Also note that you can make the timer more accurate by storing the start/stop as Date objects, then subtracting them and calculating the seconds. No need for a rather inaccurate `setInterval()`

Comment: @caramba  I 'm returning  `0` value

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  I forgot the `async` key to remove, thanks for that.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro actually I'm trying to get how long a user registers in a page and get time it spend after clicking a submit button

Comment: @Dre so that basically means that you want to calculate execution time of your registration method

Answer (score 1):

As many have pointed out, you need to move `cons` into the global scope, I'd also recommend using [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) as it gives a more accurate time over `Date.now()`. Another point, you want to know the difference before calling the AJAX request otherwise it's more of the time difference between the user clicking `start` then `stop` and then the request finishing rather than just the user clicking `start` and then `stop`.

```
var cons = null;

$(".start").click(function () {
    cons = performance.now();
});

$('.stop').click(function () {
    alert(performance.now() - cons); //Difference in Milliseconds

    $.ajax({
        url: "Register_c/register_data",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            registration: {
                TIN: '123'
            }
        },
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert('failed');
        }
    });
});
```

```js
var cons = null;

$(".start").click(function() {
  cons = performance.now();
});

$('.stop').click(function() {
  console.log("Call to stop took " + ( performance.now() - cons) + " milliseconds.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="start">Start</button>
<button class="stop">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var sec =0;
var cons =0;
var start = $('#start').click(function() { 
  siID = setInterval(function() {
    cons = sec++;
   console.log(cons);
  }, 1000);
  return cons;
});

$('#stop').click(function() {
alert(cons);
  $.ajax({
    url: "Register_c/register_data",
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: {
      registration: {
        TIN: '123'
      }
    },
    success: function(data,start) {
      window.clearInterval(siID); //stops the counting
      alert(start); //here i can't get the variable cons
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert('failed');
    }
  });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added the start function and it returns the cons and able to display that in an alert on clicking the stop function.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `cons` is a local scope so it is not available in another method where you are trying to display it, that is reason why you should move it up to a `global scope`

A variable declared outside a function, becomes GLOBAL.

A global variable has global scope: All scripts and functions on a web page can access it, and that's what you need.

But also I would recommend you to use  `console.time` (non-standard) to measure execution time of your registration method:

```
console.time('someFunction');

someFunction(); // run whatever needs to be timed in between the statements

console.timeEnd('someFunction');
```

or you could use the standard `performance.now()` API, like so:

```
var t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
```

I hope this will help you..